# À la fin d'une conversation, on me dit "vas-y": de quoi s'agit-il?

Tags: usage, interjections, injonctions

J'ai une conversation avec un interlocuteur; je termine en lui disant "aurevoir/à tout de suite/bye/à demain", et il me répond systématiquement "**vas-y**". C'est une forme *impérative* mais il n'y a aucune injonction dans le ton. Dans l'article wikipedia sur [l'impératif](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imp%C3%A9ratif_%28grammaire%29), il y a l'exemple "D'accord, vas-y, à ton match de foot !". Une permission ou une forme de "capitulation", ça varie.

L'usage auquel je suis davantage habitué c'est une variante sous forme d'*encouragement* ou d'*impatience* dans un contexte familier ("vas-y, il n'y a aucun danger", "mais vas-y!", "vas-y donc... qu'est-ce que tu attends pour y aller?").

Complètement à la fin de [cet article](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aller) sur le verbe *aller*, je trouve une référence au parler familier: **vas-y voir/allez-y voir**. Je me dis que c'est probablement relié... Je comprends le sens, mais pas l'usage; quand je quitte quelqu'un, je ne suis pas motivé par la curiosité.

---

**Q.** De quoi s'agit-il? Est-ce une forme française du "go ahead" en anglais? Est-ce couramment utilisé?

Comment: Ton interlocuteur est de quelle région et de quelle couche sociale ? Es-tu sûr d'avoir bien entendu ? Je ne vois pas ce qu'il veut dire.

Comment: @Gilles Il s'agit d'une jeune adulte de la région de Paris(m'a-t-il dit); en fait lui et un de ses amis s'expriment ainsi. Oui je t'assure, il me dit "vas-y" lool.

Comment: I can confirm that people say this to end a conversation. I hear it also in more formal contexts as "Allez-y!". Although it seems to be harmless in style, I always have the wrong feeling, the other person is sending me away and is expressing displeasure about something. Like: "Go away!".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Used this way, "Vas-y" is a slang equivalent of "Come on" in English. It can be used to encourage or beg your interlocutor to do something.

It is used mostly by youngsters in casual, friend to friend situations.

Comment: +1, On peut aussi trouver « Z'y-va », qui est la version en « Verlan ».

Comment: Verlan = à l'envers in reverse.

Comment: Thanks, it feels different as one is _come_ while the other is _go_ but I get your meaning! It makes some sense. I'll try it in English to see how people react to that...

Comment: Used at the end of a conversation, "vas-y" does not mean "come on" in French. But "go !", without the intend to encourage or beg your interlocutor to do something.

Comment: The OP here is clearly talking about the slangy usage of "vas-y" if I'm not mistaken. It is not a regional expression nor a personal fantasy of the speaker, but a very common expression among youngsters in casual situations, similar to the practice of ending sentences with a useless "quoi".

Answer (score 8):

Bonsoir,

La réponse choisie ne répond pas du tout à la question. L'expression "vas-y" dans ce contexte est une manière de clôturer la conversation. L'expression est généralement utilisée par deux personnes jeunes.

> (A) :  Je te laisse, je dois aller faire des courses, à plus tard!
>
> (B) :  Vas-y!

"Vas-y" est un synonyme utilisé ici pour dire "A plus tard" ou "J'ai bien compris, au revoir!". Il n'y a pas de réelle traduction en anglais, à part peut-être :

> (A) I'll see you later, I need to go shopping!
>
> (B) : Alright!

Cette expression est **familière** et il est déconseillé de l'utiliser avec des personnes que l'on connait peu. Elle est généralement utilisée entre **deux amis assez jeunes**.

Comment: Merci, bien c'est un peu ce que je laissais entendre dans un [commentaire](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12317/%C3%80-la-fin-dune-conversation-on-me-dit-vas-y-de-quoi-sagit-il/12318#comment21691_12318) avec le "vas y voir". Pour la sélection je me suis laissé guidé par le vote de la communauté essentiellement. Le vote peut changer, avec le temps. Ce qui en ressort finalement c'est que c'est familier et ça ne repose pas sur un usage solide ni certain.

Answer (score 2):

Soit c'est une expression régionale, soit c'est le style personnel de ton interlocuteur. Quand tu dis au revoir c'est que tu t'en vas donc (aller ailleurs), donc il te dit *vas-y* (ailleurs).
En tout cas, ce n'est pas une expression française métropolitaine. Je pense que c'est plutôt sa manière de s'exprimer. C'est un peu familier et des gens pourraient mal l’interpréter (le comprendre par *va-t'en*).  Tu peux parler comme ça à ton enfant, mais pas à un autre adulte. Même s'il te le dit sans méchanceté, il est préférable de ne pas employer cette expression.

Comment: Merci, en effet c'est un peu le sens qui se dégage pour moi, _vas-y ailleurs_. Suite à la question, j'ai pensé même à "voir à ses affaires", "vas y voir" ou un truc du genre. Ça fait un moment que j'ai quitté la fac. de sorte que je me demandais si c'était un truc que tout le monde disait etc. Il y a plein d'usages dont j'ignore l'existence, il faut croire.

Answer (score 2):

Il y a aussi le « vas-y ! » très vulgaire qui peut exprimer agressivement « Où tu crois aller comme ça en me disant cela ? Tu crois que je vais te laisser continuer, peut-être !» ou « Tu dis n'importe quoi ! » ou bien encore, cette expression très familière peut clore une dispute violemment, exprimer son mépris pour tout ce que l'autre a pu dire, et pourrait continuer à dire au moyen d'un ironique « Continue, ça m'intéresse ! » ou « Va te faire voir, tu me casses les pieds. »

Un élève non éduqué, d'un milieu particulier s'adressant à un adulte, à un professeur qui le réprimande répondant cela exprimerait ainsi tout son irrespect.

Answer (score 1):

I would translate `vas-y` by `go ahead`.

Comment: Ou peut-être _go right ahead_, so as to reinforce it, something. Merci!

Answer (score 1):

"Vas-y" est une expression très commune entre les jeunes, en tout cas là où j'habite en région parisienne. Mon copain a 23 (pardon  maintenant 24) ans et  je connais aussi de nombreux jeunes de cet âge qui l'utilisent… cela veut dire d'accord, qu'on va faire ce que l'on a dit que l'on allait faire :

> "je te laisse je vais faire les course - vas-y"

> "il faudra qu'on aille manger un bout chez Piconi - vas-y"

Comment: Bonjour ! Merci ! As-tu souvenir de l'avoir entendu quand tu étais ado. ou enfant ? Penses-tu que dans un collège privé ou à l'extérieur des grands centres on l'entendrait moins ?

Answer (score 0):

telle qu'elle est citée, je n'ai jamais entendu cette réponse en France métro'.

Un emploi voisin, sous forme de défi, correspondrait au célèbre : “Go ahead, make my day” de Clint Eastwood ; et ça, je l'ai entendu, de même que le verlan : « z'y va ! ».

Mais si vous n'êtes pas d'accord, allez-y, commentez.